# OCaml recursive function int list -> int -> (int list * int list)

Tags: ocaml

Studying for a midterm and was looking through some old exam questions. This one doesn't have a solution posted and is stumping me:

> `partition`: int list -> int -> (int list * int list) divides its
>   first argument into two lists, one containing all elements less than
>   its second argument, and the other all the elements greater than or
>   equal to its second argument. `partition` [5;2;10;4] 4 = ([2],
>   [5;10;4])

oh, and i'm supposed to be able to find the solution **without using an auxiliary function**

here is as far as i've gotten:

```
let rec partition l n = match l with 
    | [] -> ([], []) (* must return this type *)
    | x :: xs -> if x < n then (* append x to first list, continue recursing *)
                    else (* append x to second list, continue recursing *)
```

normally, I'd use an aux function with an extra parameter to store the pair of lists i'm building, but that can't be done here. i'm a bit stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `let in` construction to match the return value of the recursive call:

```
let rec partition l n = match l with 
    | [] -> ([], [])
    | x :: xs -> let a, b = partition xs n in
                    if x < n then (x::a), b
                    else          a, (x::b);;
```